# Cannot carry out aggregate query in play slick

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, slick

I am trying to write a query that can find that max of rows using the the aggregate function. However I get errors when I try to run the code

Here is my sample code below

```
def aggregate (): Future[[Person]]  = db.run {

    people.map(_.age).max.result

  }
```

I am getting this error when i run the code

```
type mismatch;
 found   : PersonRepository.this.dbConfig.profile.ProfileAction[Option[Int],PersonRepository.this.dbConfig.profile.api.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
    (which expands to)  slick.sql.FixedSqlAction[Option[Int],slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
 required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[models.Person,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
```

Please help take a look and see what's wrong, Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error am getting    ```type mismatch;
 found   : PersonRepository.this.dbConfig.profile.ProfileAction[Option[Int],PersonRepository.this.dbConfig.profile.api.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
    (which expands to)  slick.sql.FixedSqlAction[Option[Int],slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
 required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[models.Person,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]```

Answer (score 0):

Future[[Person]] - i guess this should be Future[Person].

Answer (score 0):

I later tried this and it worked

```
def agg (): Future[Option[Int]]  = db.run {
    people.map(_.age).max.result
  }
```